# Loading images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, loading

I am working on a Blackjack game in JavaScript, and I have the following function:

```
function loadImages(){
var imagesNum = 0;
var imagesLoaded = 0;

//make sure the cardRects array is 0 before repopulating
while(cardRects.length > 0){
    cardRects.pop();
    cardImages.pop();
}

for(var i = 0; i <= playerNum; i++){
    cardRects[i] = [];
    cardImages[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < playerHands[i].length; j++){
        imagesNum++;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i <= playerNum; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < playerHands[i].length; j++){
        cardImages[i][j] = new Image();
        cardImages[i][j].onload = function(){
            imagesLoaded++;
            console.log("imagesLoaded = " + imagesLoaded + " and imagesNum = " + imagesNum);
            if(imagesLoaded == imagesNum){
                console.log("Images loaded!");
                draw();
            }
        }
        if(i == playerNum && j == 1 && !showdown){
            console.log("Not showdown yet, so only see back of dealer's 2nd card.");
            cardImages[i][j].src = "images/cards/backsandpips/Red_Back.png";
        }
        else{
            console.log("Assigning card image...");
            cardImages[i][j].src = playerHands[i][j].imageFile;
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, after all the card images are loaded, the `draw()` function is called. The end of the `draw()` function contains a part where, if the round has ended, the winnings are calculated and a message is shown with the results. This fails roughly half the time. In my most recent test, the following is shown in the console:

[image]

This is followed by:

```
imagesLoaded = 1 and imagesNum = 24
...
imagesLoaded = 23 and imagesNum = 24
```

then

```
imagesLoaded = 1 and imagesNum = 24
...
imagesLoaded = 24 and imagesNum = 24
```

`loadImages()` is called only once at a time, so my two questions are:

(1) Why does the console first show "[24] Assigning card image..." *twice*? The expected course of events is that it shows this message once and goes straight to actually loading the images.
(2) Why are only 23 out of 24 images loaded before the image loading process restarts and finally completes?

I should say that this error only occurs when `loadImages()` is called at the end of a round, not at any other point.

Is there some intricacy to loading images in JavaScript that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I would just use CSS background images and forget all the JS image loading...or even better: put all the card images in one image and use CSS sprites. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

Comment: @Diodeus I think that this game is likely using canvas, especially if he has a "draw" method. I think manual images are preferred then.

Comment: I am indeed using canvas (with kinetic.js)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks as though the console displays "[24] Assigning card image..." multiple times because that text is displayed whenever i is not equal to playerNum. Your inner for loop runs this code to display text for each card in playerHands when the first for loop hasn't gotten to the point where i == playerNum.

As for the problem with loading 23/24 images and then restarting, I can only offer the debugging suggestion of printing the values of i and j to the console at the same point you print imagesLoaded and imageNum. That way you can see whether the entire for loop restarts before loading all 24 images.

Good luck!

Comment: Just to be clear, the message "[24] Assigning card image..." means that it has shown the message "Assigning card image..." 24 times. This is what I want it to show, but it then goes on to show the message _another_ 24 times, which I don't get.

Comment: I just tried your debugging suggestion, and the console says "i = 8, j = 3" every time I print imagesLoaded and imagesNum. Which is presumably not what it's supposed to do...